# extended permission publish_actions

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post an action on user's timeline. I have 2 users, developer and normal user(not registred in app) and i can post on developer page  but can't normal user

here my code

```
FB.api('/me/MYNAMESPACE:MYACTION?BYOBJECT=' + link, 'post',
   function(response) {
      var msg = 'Error occured';
      if (!response || response.error) {
         if (response.error) {
            msg += '\n\nSomething wrong \n\n' + response.error.message; 
         }
         alert(msg);
      }
      else {
         alert('Done! Please check your activity log');
      }
});
```

"link" is encoded url
sendbox mode is off and permition "publish_actions" in extended permissions is checked

Comment: do you want to post on "normal user's" timeline on behalf on "developer user"?

Comment: Has your action been approved yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the action isn't *approved* you cannot post as a regular user. Only developers can do this.

Submit your action for approval.

Comment: I submited action but its on pending, how much time it takes?? ty for help